# Need help on using SQL Query in Crystal Reports on Vb.NET 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm using MySQL with Vb.Net 2010 and Crystal Reports and to be honest I'm a complete noob when it comes to using Sql Queries. The problem is, I want to generate a report that will show the service fee from a transaction a person made while also showing the items bought, and their quantity and prices, basically a bill. I created a command from the data source I created in crystal reports and it contains this query:

`SELECT t.transaction_code,t.fee,t.service_type,t.date_sched,total_bill, s.item_code, s.quantity_sold, i.item_description, i.price, CONCAT(p.fname,' ',p.mi,' ',p.lname),p.address FROM tbl_transaction AS t, tbl_sale AS s, tbl_item AS i, tbl_profile as p WHERE t.transaction_code = '{?trans_code}' AND s.transaction_code = t.transaction_code AND i.item_code = s.item_code AND p.id='{?p_id}'`

It all works fine if I use that, the report shows everything like the persons name, transaction code, service type and its fee as well as all the items bought and the total bill. The problem is, if in that certain transaction, the said person only required services and did not buy any items, the report will just be blank. What I want is that the report should still be able to display the person's name, transaction code, service type and its fee, etc., even without buying an item. I know it's kind of hard to understand and it's also hard for me to explain, but I really need help right now.

Since I can't post images yet since I'm a new user. I'll just post a link to where I uploaded the structures of my tables:

http://oi42.tinypic.com/xogw9k.jpg

I also have a table called link_profile_transaction which does what it says and another table for the services which is linked to the services and fee from the transaction table(tbl_transaction) though it isn't included in the query.
http://oi41.tinypic.com/fqm2b.jpg

The links are legit and safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must left join the items table to the service table.

Not really certain about the schema of your table, I am providing below for you to edit if it does not work as is.

```
SELECT t.transaction_code,t.fee,t.service_type,… s.item_code, s.quantity_sold,
i.item_description, i.price, CONCAT(p.fname,' ',p.mi,' ',p.lname),p.address

FROM tbl_transaction AS t, tbl_sale AS s, tbl_profile as p
LEFT JOIN tbl_item AS i ON i.item_code = s.item_code
WHERE t.transaction_code = '{?trans_code}' 
AND s.transaction_code = t.transaction_code AND 
p.id='{?p_id}'
```

Comment: Ummmm, as I said, I'm still kinda new at using sql queries. Can you give me a sample of using the JOIN function? Maybe you can just use the query I gave with my question to incorporate the JOIN command?

Comment: Hmmm. I'll try what you said. I'll just ask again if I still don't manage to figure it out.

Comment: If it does not work out, you should include the structures of the tables in your post.

Comment: I would post the structures right now. But don't really quite know how I should post them here in stacoverflow.com since I'm just new here. Should I just type them in my post or is there a better way for them to be shown? Maybe an image?

Comment: Well I guess I still can't post images since I'm a new user which is kind of a pain. I already made screenshots of the table structures too.

Comment: after you click the edit button under your post, an image icon will appear right above the post editor. use it to add images.

Comment: I just posted them to an image hosting site since I'm still not allow to post images since I'm a new user. Just check the links in my edited post. There's 2 of them.

Comment: I managed to fix it! I changed the query into this and it worked like a charm! SELECT t.transaction_code,t.fee,t.service_type,t.date_sched,total_bill, s.item_code, s.quantity_sold, i.item_description, i.price, CONCAT(p.fname,' ',p.mi,' ',p.lname),p.address FROM tbl_profile AS p, tbl_transaction AS t LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_sale AS s ON t.transaction_code = s.transaction_code LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_item AS i ON s.item_code = i.item_code WHERE t.transaction_code = '{?trans_code}' AND p.id='{?p_id}'

Comment: Since the answer was helpful and you no longer need help on the issue, you should accept the answer to mark the thread